# Trouble deploying to Google App Engine - request invalid for unspecified reason

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment

I am deploying an update to my Google App Engine (GAE) app on the cloud through Eclipse (I have the GAE plug in and everything set up). However, it tells me that it is unable to update the app, error posting to GAE, request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

[image]

I tried researching this problem online and this link here seems to be a similar issue. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3759
But a clear solution is not provided. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml has app id with a newline and the invalid words "Seen by Jessica". Remove and make it something similar to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>mbtaproject-1212</application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. @Zeehad